# Socket.io and Express > v4 - connections are stacking weirdly

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

after some struggling I have managed to run socket.io with express version > v4 and now I experience some weird behaviour which I can't figure out.

First let me explain my example.

I have built a test backend in which a user can login.
Right after login the user only sees a list with currently online users.
How do I get the currently online users?

Well. For this example every user, that has logged into the backend section is "online" and therefore should be displayed in that list.

Now to the code.

Backend router with io function end emits:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  // console.log("socket io req response: ",req.app.get('io') );
  if(!req.session.user[0].io){
    req.app.get('io').on('connection', function(socket){ // Gets executed when user connects to /backend/
      var currentUser = req.session.user[0].name; // save username according to session
      req.session.user[0].io = true;
      console.log("IO SESSION SET : "+ req.session.user[0].io +" for user " + currentUser);
      // console.log('User connected : ' + currentUser); // Log user to server


      req.app.get('io').emit('cameOnline', currentUser); // emit function cameOnline to client js

      socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        // console.log('User: '+req.session.user[0].name+' disconnected.'); // Log disconnected user to server
        req.session.user[0].io = false;
        console.log("IO SESSION SET : "+ req.session.user[0].io +" for user " + currentUser);
        req.app.get('io').emit('wentOffline', currentUser); // emit wentOffline to client js
      });
    });
  }
  // res.render('backend', { title: 'Backend' });
  // console.log(req.session.user[0].name);

  /*
  -------------------------
  #########################
  IF EVERYTHING FAILS - THE CODE BELOW IS THE NORMAL RENDER WITHOUT SOCKET IO
  #########################
  -------------------------
  */

  if (req.session && req.session.user) { // Check if session exists
    // lookup the user in the DB by pulling their email from the session
    User.getUser({ name: req.session.user.name }, function (err, user) {
      if (!user) {
        console.log("No User found");
        // if the user isn't found in the DB, reset the session info and
        // redirect the user to the login page
        // console.log(user);
        req.session.reset();
        res.redirect('/login');
      } else {
        // expose the user to the template
        res.locals.user = user;
        // render the dashboard page


        function passOnlineUsers(callback){ // Looks for All users who are online
          User.getOnlineUsers({}, function(err, res, fields){
            // console.log(res);
            if (err) throw err;
            callback(err, res);
          });
        }

        passOnlineUsers(function(err, result){
          res.render('backend', { title: 'Backend', viewer: req.session.user[0], online: result });
          // res.render('backend', { title: 'Backend', viewer: "", online: result });
        });
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
});
```

Before establishing the socket.io connection I check if the users session already says that he has one. If not -> then proceed to create a connection.

Then the function "cameOnline" gets emited to the client like so : `req.app.get('io').emit('cameOnline', currentUser);`

Now to the client side code:

```
socket.on('cameOnline', function(name){
  console.log(name + " connected.");
  var $li = $('<li/>');
  $li.addClass(name);
  if($('#onlineUsers .'+name).length == 0){
    console.log(name + " is about to be added");
    $li.text(" "+ name);
    $('#onlineUsers').append($li);
  }else{
    console.log("no new user");
  }
  // $('#onlineUsers').append($("<span>").text(" " + name)).addClass(name);
});

socket.on('wentOffline', function(name){
  console.log(name +" is about to go offline");
  var toDel = $('#onlineUsers li.'+name);
  toDel.remove();
});
```

The client side listens to the "cameOnline" emit and adds the user if he is not already in the list.

Similar behavior with the disconnect function. Pretty self explained.

**Now to the issue:**

When I log into the backend with user : "Noa" i see user "Noa" correctly displayed in the list.

Now when I open a separate browser and login with another user : "Albert" the user gets correctly added live to the online list on both clients.

Perfect.

**BUT**

When I disconnect with user : "Albert" the online user list for user "Noa" gets cleared completely, as if noone was online.

When I refresh the page as user "Noa" I suddenly see both users as online again although the second user isn't online any more.

When I check the console on my client I see duplicated logs of `console.log(name + " is about to be added");` as if there is some sort of caching. The more I refresh the more user "copies" I have. 
The "copies" of the user I am online with get incremented and the one weird copy of the user who WAS online stays there as well. All the time.

Any ideas what I am doing massively wrong here?

** EDIT **

bin/www io declaration:

```
/**
* Socket IO
*/
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
app.set('io',io);
```

Comment: How does `req.app.get('io').on('connection', ...)` work?  I have not seen that construction before.  Usually, we would just see `io.on('connection', ...)`.  It sounds like your session is not being set correctly so you're getting cross-wired sessions between different users.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will provide the code that sets io globally as soon as I get home. What I can tell you now is that I searched for a way to make io available in the whole app. So I can use it across my route files. So io gets set in the bin/www and the app.js and made globally accessible so I can use it in routes/backend.js for example.